# AFRAME Animating in Text on hover issue

Tags: animation, text, aframe

https://jsfiddle.net/ykma6r0d/1/

Link to a demo ^

HMTL:

```
<a-scene>
  <!-- CAMERA CURSOR -->
  <a-entity id="camera" camera mouse-cursor look-controls wasd-controls>
    <a-cursor fuse="true" color="red"></a-cursor>
  </a-entity>
  <a-entity id="myTarget" scale="1 .001 1" look-at="#camera" text="color: black;align: center; value: YAYA!; width: 6; wrap-count: 10" animation__1="startEvents: in;property: scale; dur: 200; from: 1 .001 7; to: 1 1 1" animation__2="startEvents: out;property: scale; dur: 200; from: 1 1 1; to: 1 .001 1"></a-entity>
  <a-circle name-on-hover="target: #myTarget" position="-2 0 -10" material="color: blue" material="opacity:.75" look-at="#camera" animation="property: position;easing: easeInSine;loop:true;dir: alternate;dur: 2000;to:-2 .2 -10">
  </a-circle>
</a-scene>
```

JS:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("name-on-hover", {
  schema: {
    target: {
      type: "selector",
      default: ""
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    var target = this.data.target;
    var el = this.el;
    this.setupNamePos();
    el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      target.emit("in"); // animate in
    });
    el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      target.emit("out"); // animate out
    });
  },
  setupNamePos: function() {
    var name = this.data.target; // get name element
    var elPos = this.el.getAttribute("position"); // get the pos of hovered element

    name.setAttribute("position", {
      //set name position relevant to hovered element
      x: elPos.x,
      y: elPos.y + 2,
      z: elPos.z
    });
  }
});
```

I have two elements, a circle and a text element

Circle element: a text above it needs to animate in on hover. In my JS, i have it set so that it grabs the position of the circle and then sets that position to my text element but before it does that it increases the Y position by 2 units.

For some reason, my animation loops like crazy when i hover the mouse over the circle. At first i thought that it could be because the text element is overlapping the circle, losing the hover event. However i tried moving the text element to a different location by modifying the X and Z as well.. but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the text expands, it gets in the way of the cursors raycaster - and the `mouseleave` gets emitted.

You can limit the entities the cursor can click using the `objects` property.

```
<a-cursor objects='clickable'> </a-cursor>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4upn3b5z/1/).

Comment: Perfect, it worked!, i wish the docs were more detailed and gave small example code.

Comment: @user1986245 glad i could help. This feature is mentioned in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/cursor.html#configuring-the-cursor-through-the-raycaster-component), though maybe an example with switching clickable targets could be a nice idea